# Form Returning ?query instead of returning search results page

Tags: html, forms, search

We have a large search box on our homepage that just stopped working after a recent update from our vendor. I'm trying to debug the issue but I could really use an extra set of eyes. Instead of returning a list of courses it's returning "?query" to the current page URL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Affected Page: https://ce.harpercollege.edu/

Code:

```
<form action="https://ce.harpercollege.edu//search/publicCourseAdvancedSearch.do" class="search-form" id="search-form" method="GET" role="form" target="_blank"> 
  <label for="quick-search">BECOME MORE</label>
  <span class="search-btn-span" id="search-btn-span">
    <input name="method" type="hidden" value="doPaginatedSearch" />
    <input name="showInternal" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <input name="cspIndex" type="hidden" value="true" />
    <input name="isPageDisplayed" type="hidden" value="true" />
    <input class="form-control" name="courseSearch.courseDescriptionKeyword" placeholder="Search Course Number, Title, or Keyword..." type="text" />
    <button type="submit"></button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Working Search URL:

```
https://ce.harpercollege.edu/search/publicCourseAdvancedSearch.do?method=doPaginatedSearch&showInternal=false&cspIndex=true&isPageDisplayed=true&courseSearch.courseDescriptionKeyword=garden&courseSearch.disciplineCode=&courseSearch.partialCourseNumber=&courseSearch.courseCategoryStringArray=0&courseSearch.sectionSemesterIdString=&courseSearch.sectionInstructorName=&courseSearch.sectionAccreditingAssociationStringArray=0&courseSearch.sectionDayOfWeekStringArray=0&courseSearch.sectionStartTimeStringArray=0&courseSearch.sectionStartMonthStringArray=0&courseSearch.filterString=availforreg
```

Comment: Not sure if I've understood your problem exactly but a search result gets opened in a new window if you hit enter/ press the submit button. If you just want the user to be taken to the result of their search then stop using `target="_blank"`

Comment: I removed the target and it don't do anything to fix the issue.

Comment: It's working as expected for me. 1) I visit: https://ce.harpercollege.edu/ 2) type in 'software' 3) hit enter 4) page reloads with search results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue. An old script was hiding in JS and was breaking the form. Sorry for being a bother.